# Case Sensitive POJO to Json mapping Hybris

Tags: java, json, post, case-sensitive, objectmapper

How can I keep the original case of the keys when writing the object to json?

POJO-Class:

```
public class LeadRequest
{
    private String AccountName;
    private String AccountAlias;
    private String BPID;
    private String CustomerType;
    private String Email;
    private String LocationType;
    private String APRID;
    private String APRDistributorName;
    private String EngagedwithRAOrDistributor;

    public String getBPID()
    {
        return BPID;
    }
    public void setBPID(final String bPID)
    {
        BPID = bPID;
    }
    public String getEngagedwithRAOrDistributor()
    {
        return EngagedwithRAOrDistributor;
    }
    public void setEngagedwithRAOrDistributor(final String engagedwithRAOrDistributor)
    {
        EngagedwithRAOrDistributor = engagedwithRAOrDistributor;
    }
}
```

Service-class:

```
public void submitLeadRequest(final LeadRequest lead)
{
    try
    {
        final String endPoint = Config.getParameter(ServicesConstants.API_URL);
        final HttpPost request = new HttpPost(endPoint);
        request.addHeader(ServicesConstants.CONTENT_TYPE, ServicesConstants.APPLICATION_JSON);
        request.addHeader(ServicesConstants.CLIENT_ID, Config.getParameter(ServicesConstants.CLIENT_ID));
        request.addHeader(ServicesConstants.CLIENT_SECRET, Config.getParameter(ServicesConstants.CLIENT_SECRET));

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final String jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(lead);
        final StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonString);
        request.setEntity(entity);
        final RequestConfig requestConfig = getRequestConfig(API_TIMEOUT_LONG);
        final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);      
    }
}
```

Currently the Post Request json generated is:

```
{
  "accountAlias" : "No Account Alias",
  "accountName" : "REI AUTOMATION INC",
  "customerType" : "OEM",
  "aprid" : "002",
  "bpid" : "0099105850",
  "locationType" : "Research & Development",
  "email" : "john.smith@jefftestaccount.com",
  "engagedwithRAOrDistributor" : "",
  "aprdistributorName" : "002-CED Royal Industrial Elec"
}
```

But the post request is failing giving HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error because of case sensitive keys in request json for the system being called

Therefore, the desired Request Json is:
[image]

Comment: Can you send imports?

Comment: Do you use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`, you can specify final name for each field using `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty` for example:

```java
@JsonProperty("AccountName")
private String AccountName;
```

Or you can “tell” to your mapper to use fields instead of getters for creating  a final JSON. In order to do so you can just configure your mapper class as follows:

```java
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```